# MSAL.js acquireTokenSilent resulting null token

Tags: javascript, axios, azure-active-directory, msal.js

I'm working with an existing Single Page Application that we recently moved from an On-Prim auth provider to Azure Active Directory and MSAL.js We're using the WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationMiddleware on the backend to secure the WebAPI endpoints.

The API is secure, users can login and everything works. The problem start at around the time the token expires at the one hour mark. The tokenSilent method returns a token with a null accessToken.

I found this issue on Guthub.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/736

The short and dirty here, token requests that are single scoped to the application will only return refreshed id_token but not a refreshed accessToken. The solution is to add an additional scope. If I do it throws an error that says **Client ID can only be provided as a single scope**

Any help would be appreicated

```
var clientApplication;

// Enter Global Config Values & Instantiate MSAL Client application
window.msalConfig = {
    auth: {
            clientId: 'obfuscated'
            , authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
            , validateAuthority: true
            , redirectUri: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/msal.html" //http://localhost:58541/msal.html
            }
    , cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage"
            }
    , graphScope: {
            scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read", "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send" ]
            }
    , appScope: {
            scopes: ["obfuscated"]
            }
};

axios.interceptors.request.use(async function (options) {

    var scope = window.msalConfig.appScope;     //based on where the request is going, will need to decide what token to get.
    var tokenType = "AuthToken";                //this probably ins't needed after rewriting all existing jquery.ajax hooks
    if (options.url.includes("microsoft")) {
        scope = window.msalConfig.graphScope;
        tokenType = "GraphToken";               //this probably ins't needed after rewriting all existing jquery.ajax hooks
    }

    self.Loading({ State: true, Title: "Working on it..." });

    options.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + await tokenSilent(tokenType, scope);

    return options;
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Axios Request Error: ', error);
    return promise.reject(error);
});


          async function tokenSilent(tokenType, scope) {
            console.log('Axios Request VERBOS: main.js.tokenSilent');
            return await clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(scope)
                .then(async function (token) {
                    Cookies.set(tokenType, token.accessToken); // "Bearer " +
                    self.LoginID(token.account.userName);
                    return token.accessToken;
                }, async function (error) {
                    return await tokenPopup(scope);
                    console.log(error);
                });
        };

        async function tokenPopup(tokenType, scope) {
            console.log('Axios Request VERBOS: main.js.tokenPopup');
            return await clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(scope)
                .then(async function (token) {
                    Cookies.set(tokenType, token.accessToken); //"Bearer " +
                    self.LoginID(token.account.userName);
                    return token.accessToken;
                }, async function (error) {
                    return await loginPopup(scope);
                    console.log(error);
                });
        };

        async function loginPopup(tokenType, scope) {
            console.log('Axios Request VERBOS: main.js.loginPopup');
            window.location.hash = "/auth";
        };
```

Is there a way to extend the tokenlifecycle of my enterprise application, or is my code wrong and it's not getting the refreshed token?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your token life time value for your enterprise application. We use to create a policy on PowerShell by connecting to Azure AD manually as per the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)

​
Now we can use CA policy to extend or change the token lifetime value for the application. Kindly refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime).​